# How to concatenate 2 keys in the same dictionary if the have similar name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, concatenation

I am doing a small project where I develop a small tool that analyses data from chemical experiment.

I imported data from CSV and made some adjustments with Pandas until I ended up with this dictionary:

```
 '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [1, 1, 1],
 '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [2, 2, 2],
 '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-6': [3, 3, 3],
 '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-24': [4, 4, 4],
 '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [5, 5, 5],
 '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-24': [6, 6, 6],
 '7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [7, 7, 7],
 '7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [8, 8, 8],
 '7_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [9, 9, 9],
 '8_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [10, 10, 10],
 '8_batch_pfoa_fg': [11, 11, 11],
 '8_batch_genx_fg': [12, 12, 12],
 '8_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [13, 13, 13],
 '8_batch_pfos_fg': [14, 14, 14]}
```

Each key represents the following:
**6**: number of experiment
**batch**: type of experiment
**pfoa**: type of chemical
**zif-8-fg-6**: type of metal used

Not to go into deep details, some experiments have the same variables but the only difference is the batch number.
for example:

```
7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [7, 7, 7]
8_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [10, 10, 10]
```

That means that the experiment number 8 is a redo for experiment number 7.

I want to write a code that checks if the type of experiment, type of chemical, and type of metal used are the same. Then, it will concatenate them into 1 key with 6 values.
as an example:

```
7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [7, 7, 7]
8_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [10, 10, 10]
```

should turn into:

```
7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10]
```

the number of batches is no longer relevant after merging the keys. It can be anything.

I tried to split the name with `split_name = point.split('_')` and compare `split_name[1]` and `split_name[2]` and `split_name[3]` but I couldn't figure out how to loop the key in the dictionary and compare it to the other keys.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can be iterated over by key, value, or both (i.e., `items()`).  The code below takes advantage of that.  The only tricky part is that I use an intermediate dictionary, `data_mapper` to facilitate the transforms between `raw_data` and `merged_data`.

```
from pprint import pprint

raw_data = {
    '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [1, 1, 1],
    '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [2, 2, 2],
    '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-6': [3, 3, 3],
    '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-24': [4, 4, 4],
    '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [5, 5, 5],
    '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-24': [6, 6, 6],
    '7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [7, 7, 7],
    '7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [8, 8, 8],
    '7_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [9, 9, 9],
    '8_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [10, 10, 10],
    '8_batch_pfoa_fg': [11, 11, 11],
    '8_batch_genx_fg': [12, 12, 12],
    '8_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [13, 13, 13],
    '8_batch_pfos_fg': [14, 14, 14]
}

data_mapper = {}
merged_data = {}

for raw_key, raw_values in raw_data.items():

    # create a key excluding experiment number
    mapper_key = tuple(raw_key.split("_")[1:])
    
    # extend merged data entry if already exists
    if mapper_key in data_mapper:
        merged_key = data_mapper[mapper_key]
        merged_data[merged_key].extend(raw_values)

    # create merged data entry if does not exist
    else:
        data_mapper[mapper_key] = raw_key
        merged_data[raw_key] = raw_values

pprint(merged_data)
```

Output:

```
{'6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-24': [4, 4, 4],
 '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-6': [3, 3, 3],
 '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8],
 '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10],
 '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-24': [6, 6, 6],
 '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13],
 '8_batch_genx_fg': [12, 12, 12],
 '8_batch_pfoa_fg': [11, 11, 11],
 '8_batch_pfos_fg': [14, 14, 14]}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method creates a new `dict` to keep the unique items. It keeps the valid part of the keys using slicing `[2:]`.

```py
d =  {'6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [1, 1, 1],
 '6_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [2, 2, 2],
 '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-6': [3, 3, 3],
 '6_batch_genx_zif-8-fg-24': [4, 4, 4],
 '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [5, 5, 5],
 '6_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-24': [6, 6, 6],
 '7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [7, 7, 7],
 '7_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24': [8, 8, 8],
 '7_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [9, 9, 9],
 '8_batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6': [10, 10, 10],
 '8_batch_pfoa_fg': [11, 11, 11],
 '8_batch_genx_fg': [12, 12, 12],
 '8_batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6': [13, 13, 13],
 '8_batch_pfos_fg': [14, 14, 14]}


d_new = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    if k[2:] in d_new:
        d_new[k[2:]] = d_new[k[2:]] + v
    else:
        d_new[k[2:]] = v

for k,v in d_new.items():
    print(k,v)
```

result:

```
batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-6 [1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10]
batch_pfoa_zif-8-fg-24 [2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8]
batch_genx_zif-8-fg-6 [3, 3, 3]
batch_genx_zif-8-fg-24 [4, 4, 4]
batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-6 [5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 13, 13, 13]
batch_pfos_zif-8-fg-24 [6, 6, 6]
batch_pfoa_fg [11, 11, 11]
batch_genx_fg [12, 12, 12]
batch_pfos_fg [14, 14, 14]
```